# Not sure how to use Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

With this models

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length = 200)

class EventSchedule(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    sales_start = models.DateTimeField('Sales start')
    sales_finish = models.DateTimeField('Sales end')
```

How to effectively get all Events objects that have at least one EventSchedule which is active and within sales start and end period?

The filter for EventSchedule objects is

```
filter(active = True, sales_start__lte = now, sales_finish__gte = now)
```

but I need Event objects instead of EventSchedule objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the double-underscore syntax to traverse relations:

```
Event.objects.filter(eventschedule__active=True, 
                     eventschedule__sales_start__lte=now,
                     eventschedule__sales_finish__gte=now)
```

**Edited** Actually, the above code will show events which have schedules which match any of those criteria, even if they are not the same schedule. This actually requires a sub-query, which can be done like this:

```
Event.objects.filter(eventschedule__in=EventSchedule.objects.filter(
    (active=True, sales_start__lte=now, sales_finish__gte=now))
```

**Third try** is this any better?

```
Event.objects.filter(id__in=EventSchedule.objects.values_list('event').filter(
    (active=True, sales_start__lte=now, sales_finish__gte=now)).distinct()
```

Comment: I think that used this way I will get an object for every EventSchedule (Event object will be duplicated) I need a way to group Events so I can also use automatic paging for Event objects

Comment: No, it will give only unique Events. However there is a separate problem with my solution, so I've given a new version above.

Comment: The second solutions do almost what you say but with one unnecessary join which break things http://pastebin.com/MbBm5DvU

Comment: `SELECT "tg_events"."id",
       "tg_events"."isactive",
FROM "tg_events"
INNER JOIN "tg_eventschedules" ON ("tg_events"."id" = "tg_eventschedules"."event")
WHERE "tg_eventschedules"."id" IN
    (SELECT U0."id"
     FROM "tg_eventschedules" U0
     WHERE (U0."isactive" = TRUE
            AND U0."salesbegin" <= 2012-09-13 14:04:47.387560+00:00
            AND U0."salesend" >= 2012-09-13 14:04:47.387560+00:00))`

Answer (score 0):

I just think simple:

```
events = []
obj = EventSchedule.objects.filter(active=True, sales_start__lte=now, sales_finish__gte=now)
for i in obj:
    if not i.event in events:
          events.append(i.event)
```